# Adapting RxJava 1.1.5 to Reactor Core 3.1.0.M3

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am trying to use a library that uses RxJava 1.1.5 with Spring WebFlux (i.e. Reactor Core 3.1.0.M3) but I am having trouble adapting `Observable` to `Flux`.

I thought this would be relatively straightforward, but my adapter isn't working:

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.Subscription;

public static <T> Flux<T> toFlux(Observable<T> observable) {
    return Flux.create(emitter -> {
        final Subscription subscription = observable.subscribe(new Subscriber<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(T value) {
                emitter.next(value);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                emitter.complete();
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                emitter.error(throwable);
            }
        });
        emitter.onDispose(subscription::unsubscribe);
    });
}
```

I have verified that `onNext` and `onCompleted` are both getting called in the correct order but my `Flux` is always empty. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

On a related note, why isn't there an adapter for RxJava 1 in [reactor-addons](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/tree/master/reactor-adapter/src/main/java/reactor/adapter/rxjava)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [RxJavaReactiveStreams](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaReactiveStreams) adapter to turn your `Observable` into a `Publisher`, then have `Flux.fromPublisher()` consume it.

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-reactive-streams:1.2.1'

Observable<T> o = ...

Flux.from(RxReactiveStreams.toPublisher(o));
```

> On a related note, why isn't there an adapter for RxJava 1 in reactor-addons?

They don't want to support or encourage using that old technology and I completely agree.

Comment: wouldn't dare calling it "old" in front of akarnokd :p but yeah that's the spirit: the Rx1-to-Publisher adapter path is straightforward enough that it's not worth the trouble to provide a direct adapter, plus Reactor wants to encourage using reactive streams